# Using SQL override in ODI 12C with source data server different then target

Tags: oracle-data-integrator

I am trying to load data into `OBIEE db Oracle` database using a custom source query that needs to be executed on the `CRM DB` in `ODI 12c`. I am using a default `LKM` as the source and target are on on different servers. It requires a `LKM` else the mapping is failing on source connectivity.

I can see the `C$` tables creating which are not relevant as I only need a direct load from source query to target. Can you suggest me relevant `LKM` or ways to avoid using `LKM`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As answer to your question, you can create your own LKM, at let it blank .. so no command will be executed. In this mode you can "avoid" LKM's. But, for this, you need a IKM that will "make" your query ..

I don't know exactly if there is a IKM that will work without a LKM (predefined) but, also, you can create your own IKM, easily. If you need help, please tell me

Comment: Thank You. I have created a customised IKM and LKM as suggested.